# Como eu faço este código em Minizinc?

Tags: minizinc

Como eu posso fazer este código em Minizinc?

[image: o codigo está na figura]

Eu tentei da seguinte forma:

```
constraint forall(i in nurse, j in patient where j != 1)(start[i] == min(arrive[i,j] + ((1-y[i,1,j])*H) - sum(u in patient)(dist[1,j]*y[i,1,u]), 0));
```

Mas está retornando o seguinte erro:

```
"cannot determine bounds"
```

Comment: O que exatamente representa essa expressão matemática? Confesso que a reli várias vezes e não consegui ver sentido nela.

Comment: representa que a parte da esquerda recebe o menor valor possível, calculado pela parte da direita